# Make system image of windows 8, excluding documents, just system and programs

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, windows-backup

I'm running windows 8 64bit and wanted to know how I can backup my system - JUST the current state of the system AND the programs that are installed.

I do NOT want to backup all my music/pictures/documents/videos etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you put the docs in separate partitions, you can open "Windows 7 File Recovery" (it's included in Windows 8) and then choose to backup only your system partition

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to move the files to a different partition and then backup. You're kind of going against the grain here, and I don't think you'll find a solution that specifically excludes the things a typical user actually wants to keep.

You will still end up taking an image of your profile however, and I can't think of much of a way around that. If you're looking to have a clean image for future installs, you're better off starting over and using imagex and other tools to produce your own custom install.

Answer (score 0):

With windows 8, you can use recimg.exe you can make an image of your system + apps and change the image that windows restore by default.

My advice be sure that your image is clean before set it as default.

You can see to that url to have more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt-harrington/archive/2012/04/01/create-a-windows-8-refresh-image-with-recimg-exe.aspx

recimg /CreateImage path to save the image
--> to save the image of the system

recimg /SetCurrent path to the image
--> to set as default image

recimg /ShowCurrent
--> to see the path of the current image